# Moving up list items with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I want to move up single items of a list by clicking. I'm using jQuery but it does not work.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sftbH/)

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">AAAAA</li>
    <li class="item">BBBBB</li>
    <li class="item">CCCCC</li>
    <li class="item">DDDDD</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(".item").click( function(){
    var item = $(this);
    item.insertBefore(item.before());
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sftbH/1/)***

Use `prev()` instead of `before()`

`item.insertBefore(item.prev());`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(".item").click(function () {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sftbH/2/)**